# How can I resolve a particular implementation of an interface by key with AutoFac?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac

I have been stuck with this problem for several hours now.  I inherit this code which uses the Microsoft DI framework. I need to migrate to autofac but I'm getting the below error.

[image]

```
 builder.Register<IGlobalLabeling>((c, p) =>
        {
            var type = p.TypedAs<LabelType>();
            switch(type)
            {
                case LabelType.LAND: return c.Resolve<LandLabeling>();
                case LabelType.RLSE: return c.Resolve<ResiLeaseLabeling>();
                case LabelType.RINC: return c.Resolve<ResiIncomeLabeling>();
                case LabelType.COMM: return c.Resolve<CommercialLabeling>();
                default: return c.Resolve<ResiLabeling>();

            }
        }).As<IGlobalLabeling>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Below is my constructor DI hookup:

```
public class LandLabeling : GlobalLabeling, IGlobalLabeling
{
    
}
```

This is the use case for my interface:

```
public LandDescription(Func<string, IGlobalLabeling> landLabeling)
    {
        _landLabeling = landLabeling;
    }
```

BTW this is the Microsoft DI code that works.

```
services.AddTransient<Func<string, IGlobalLabeling>>
               (serviceProvider => key =>
               {
                   switch (key)
                   {
                       case "LAND": return serviceProvider.GetService<LandLabeling>();
                       case "RLSE": return serviceProvider.GetService<ResiLeaseLabeling>();
                       case "RINC": return serviceProvider.GetService<ResiIncomeLabeling>();
                       case "COMM": return serviceProvider.GetService<CommercialLabeling>();
                       default: return serviceProvider.GetService<ResiLabeling>();

                   }

               });
```

Comment: The question seems to be more about "how can I resolve a particular implementation of an interface by key" not "how can I register multiple implementations" - registering multiple implementations is very easy, the challenge here is in picking the right one based on key. (You'll get more of the right eyes on the question if the question title is accurate.)

Answer (score 0):

There is actually an example [in the Autofac documentation](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#selection-of-an-implementation-by-parameter-value) that looks nearly identical to this. I just updated it to be a bit more explicit, but the meat of it was there to start.

The example shows how you can register an interface (in this case, the base class `CreditCard` is the interface, but for you it'd be `IGlobalLabeling`) and, based on parameter input, choose which thing to return.

```cs
builder.Register<CreditCard>(
  (c, p) =>
    {
      var accountId = p.TypedAs<string>();
      if (accountId.StartsWith("9"))
      {
        return new GoldCard(accountId);
      }
      else
      {
        return new StandardCard(accountId);
      }
    });
```

Consuming that can be done through `Func<X, Y>`.

```cs
var cardFactory = container.Resolve<Func<string, CreditCard>>();
var card = cardFactory("12345");
```

If you're on Autofac 6.4.0+, the new lambda expression component syntax can make the registration easier:

```cs
builder.Register<string, CreditCard>(
  (accountId) =>
    {
      if (accountId.StartsWith("9"))
      {
        return new GoldCard(accountId);
      }
      else
      {
        return new StandardCard(accountId);
      }
    });
```